# auto keyword behavior with references

Tags: c++, auto

Let's say I have a simple c++ class that contains a private member and a getter:

```
class MyClass
{
    private:
        double m_testValue = 1;

    public:
        double& getTestValue(){return m_testValue;}
}
```

Now let's say I want to call the getter to get my reference and edit this value (and printing before / after values)

```
auto testVal = myClassInstance.getTestValue();
std::cout << myClassInstance.getTestValue() << std::endl;
std::cout << testVal << std::endl;
testVal = 3;
std::cout << myClassInstance.getTestValue() << std::endl;
std::cout << testVal << std::endl;
```

The output is

```
1
1
1
3
```

This is not exactly what I expected since apparently, m_testValue wasn't edited. Indeed, if I replace auto with double& :

```
double& testVal = myClassInstance.getTestValue();
std::cout << myClassInstance.getTestValue() << std::endl;
std::cout << testVal << std::endl;
testVal = 3;
std::cout << myClassInstance.getTestValue() << std::endl;
std::cout << testVal << std::endl;
```

I get

```
1
1
3
3
```

Which is what I want. 
So the question is:
Is this the expected behaviour of the `auto` keyword or is it a bug? 
If this is expected, what is the reason for this behaviour? is it a technical limitation? If it by design and why?

Comment: `auto` works just like template type deduction, with one unrelated exception.

Comment: Note that in C++14 you can get the desired behaviour using `decltype(auto)`.

Comment: This comment is not about your problem. In your code there is a problem with design: a get method must be const `const double& getTestValue() const noexcept {return m_testValue;}`. In this particular case maybe return by reference it's irrilevant

Comment: @elvis.dukaj: A getter is not necessary `const`, we have for example `std::vector::at`, `std::vector::front`, `std::vector::operator[]`... And if it is the `get` prefix which make the thing `const` for you, there is free function `std::get<I>(std::tuple<Ts...>&)`...

Comment: @Jarod42 The only case is when you're retrieving an element from a container. In all other cases I think it's a bad idea: if I read getSpeed() I don't think I change the speed of the object. That's introduce only misunderstanding on the code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When `auto` is deduced, it is not deduced to the reference. It always deduces to the value. If you want to have a reference to returned value, you can have `auto&`, `const auto&` or `auto&&`.

And yes, it is by design. Any other behavior would actually be quite surprising. What is even worse, it is easy to use a reference when you want. However, imagine that `auto` would be actually deduced to the reference. How would you (syntactically) make it a value?

Comment: I didn't know about the auto& syntax! this make the purpose and usage of `auto` clearer. Thanks