# When is temporary lifetime extension useful in modern C++?

Tags: c++, lifetime, temporary-objects

In C++ you can bind return value of a function (which return value, not reference) to const reference and code will still be valid because lifetime of this temporary will be prolonged till the end of scope. For example

```
std::string get_string() {
    return "abc";
}


void f() {
    const std::string& str = get_string();
    std::cout << str; // valid, str is not dangling reference.
}
```

My question is, when is it useful, e.g. when is code like

```
A get_a();
const A& a = get_a();
```

better than the code

```
A get_a();
A a = get_a();
```

and in what way (e.g. faster, smaller binary size, etc)? What should be the implementations of `A`, `get_a` and code after calling `get_a`?

I've tested several cases by hand and in each case it seems to have the same number of copies and moves.

Let's restrict this question to current C++ standard, modern versions of compilers and builds with optimisation enabled (O2, O3 or equivalents for other compilers)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Deliberate lifetime extension of prvalues into named stack variables like this is not useful if you know exactly what's going on. Which means it is useful if you *don't know* exactly what's going on.

Say, you're in a template function. And the user is supposed to give you some object that has a `get` member function that returns some type that fits some expected behavior. Question: does `get` return a reference or a prvalue?

Answer: *you don't care*. It doesn't matter if it returns a prvalue or a reference; what matters is that what it returns can be manipulated in the fashion you expect. So you might expect `obj.get() = 10;` to work, for example.

Maybe `get` returns a reference to an object. Or maybe it returns a prvalue that is a proxy object that *acts* like a reference. In the above case, maybe it has an `operator=` overload, so that you can assign to it. You the user don't care.

So, what happens if you want to store what `get` returns for a (short) period of time? Well, you don't want to do `auto x = obj.get();`; if it returned an actual reference, you would get a copy of the reference, which is probably not what you wanted. So you do `auto &&x = obj.get();`. Lifetime extension allows this to work just as well with proxy prvalue objects as with actual references.

Comment: Nice post.  Excuse my ignorance, but why would getting a copy of a reference be a bad thing?  In what way does it not behave in the same way as the original?  I realise that `auto &&` can bind to anything and so is more adaptable but that's not the same thing.  But perhaps I misunderstand or perhaps I'm just picking nits.  Learnt some interesting stuff about `auto &&` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230480/what-does-auto-tell-us).

Comment: @PaulSanders: If you expect to be able to do `obj.get() = 5;` to assign a value to `obj`, will `auto x = obj.get(); x = 5;` do the same? If the return of `get` is a proxy, then yes. If the return of `get` is a language reference, then no. You use `auto&&` to indicate that you want to store exactly what `get` returns.

Comment: OK, I still didn't understand this so I knocked up a [demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/trQqirCpnzBglr7w), and given (say) `int& get() { ... } ... auto x = obj.get();` you can indeed not assign to `obj` via `x`.  _But why not?_  Found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37394183/5743288): `When auto is deduced, it is not deduced to the reference. It always deduces to the value`.  That is the key phrase here.  My, you have to be so careful with this language.