# What is the correct what to hold a reference to a multiply nested std::vector?

Tags: c++, reference, segmentation-fault, c++17, declaration

I'm in the process of profiling our application and found that constructs such as the following are taking up a considerable amount of time:

```
void Locations::remove_without_set_index(Item *item) {
  locations[item->x()][item->y()][item->z()].back()->LocationIndexHandler::set_index(item->LocationIndexHandler::index());
  locations[item->x()][item->y()][item->z()][item->LocationIndexHandler::index()] = locations[item->x()][item->y()][item->z()].back();
  locations[item->x()][item->y()][item->z()].pop_back();
}
```

So it seems like a reasonable approach is to grab the reference once and then use that instead of making multiple calls for it. However, when I do so as follows:

```
void Locations::remove_without_set_index(Item *item) {
  auto reference = locations[item->x()][item->y()][item->z()];
  reference.back()->LocationIndexHandler::set_index(item->LocationIndexHandler::index());
  reference[item->LocationIndexHandler::index()] = reference.back();
  reference.pop_back();
}
```

I end up getting segmentation faults and errors such as corrupted double-linked lists. The data structure is defined as follows:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<Item*>>>> locations;
```

So I'm assuming that the reference I'm grabbing is incorrect. is it possible to correctly hold the reference and if so, how?

Comment: these types of optimizations should usually be left to the compiler, make sure you are using -O3 !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [auto keyword behavior with references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37394105/auto-keyword-behavior-with-references)

Comment: @Lykos Yes, this is compilation profiling. Even then I only really gave this a second look because the block was taking up about 20% of total execution time. I wonder if the functions within the indices are tripping the compiler up?

Comment: @rjzii try rewriting the function to (const Item *item) and declaring the x y and z inline ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your reference isn't a reference. It's a copy. You need to do this:

```
auto& reference = locations[item->x][item->y][item->z];
//  ^
```

C++ is value-semantics-by-default, you have to opt-in to taking a reference.

Comment: That did the trick! Incidentally, typing out the problem actually helped jog my memory and I was on that track of wonder if `auto` wasn't holding onto a reference.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot parentheses in this expression

```
auto reference = locations[item->x()][item->y()][item->z()];
                                  ^^         ^^         ^^
```

or such a stetament

```
locations[item->x()][item->y()][item->z()].back()->LocationIndexHandler::set_index(item->LocationIndexHandler::index());
```

shall be written without the parentheses.

In any case you can also to use the following approach to define a reference

```
decltype( auto ) reference = ( locations[item->x()][item->y()][item->z()] );
```